# Retrieving image in a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I wrote a program in java to retrieve images and text data from a table. Everything is right, only when i try to retrieve an image(Blob) from the table, i get an exhausted result set error.I tried google it, but the explanation was fa too condensed. Can anyone help me with this? I will appreciate a nice explanation.

Here is the code

```
       try {
  Class.forName(classforname);
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectionurl, username, password);
  String sql = "Select * from teacherdata where teachername='" + tf1.getText() + "'";
  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);
  rs.next();
  String thename = rs.getString("teachername");
  String sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4;
  sub1 = rs.getString("sub1");
  sub2 = rs.getString("sub2");
  sub3 = rs.getString("sub3");
  sub4 = rs.getString("sub4");
  String sql2 = "select tid,tpic from teacherimages where teachername='" + tf1.getText() + "'";
  PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
  ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery(sql2);
  rs2.next();
  String Tid = rs2.getString("tid");
  Blob b = rs.getBlob("tpic");
  byte barr
   [] = new byte[(int) b.length()]; //an array is created but contains no  data
  barr = b.getBytes(3, (int) b.length());
  Image im = jInternalFrame1.getToolkit().createImage(barr);
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(im);
  JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
  Object[] row = {
   thename,
   sub1,
   sub2,
   sub3,
   sub4,
   b,
   Tid,
   icon
  };
  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

  model.addRow(row);

  jTable1.setVisible(true);
 } catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(SearchBox.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Comment: Please provide the exception.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Comment: Paste the full stack trace to question(formatted). You have quite lot of errors -resource not closed- Connection, resultset, ...

Comment: at least show the line where error occurred

Comment: added the full stack trace

Comment: Are you sure `rs.next();` or `rs2.next();` returned a result ? When there is no records returned from Database for a particular condition and When you try to access the rs.getString("teachername"); you will get this error "exhausted resultset".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the return value of next on the ResultSet.

Please consider changing your code to

```
if(result.next()){
    //  the logic 
}
```

**EDIT**
Further on the code change , please check that your tables are not empty. If your tables are empty you will not return values.

The error Exhausted Resultset set occurs when you attempt to access the result set after iterating or not checking if the result set returns data

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
  //result set logic
}
// 
resultset.getString[1] //<- will throw error Exhausted Resultset
```

Comment: What do you mean no result ? The error  `java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset` means that no data was returned by the query and you attempted to access the result set

Comment: yes i know..but how come that is possible..i have retrieved the image succesfully on a separate panel... but cant do it on the table

Comment: now i have tried to call the image object separably through a finction, and using it as a return value to add to the table..